# Mutt sent file in home directory - how to relocate

Tags: configuration, mutt

I do not want to store my sent file for mutt in my home directory. I would like to move this file to the .mutt directory.

Inside my muttrc I did this -

```
set record="~/.mutt/"
```

but this causes an error and is non functional. I do not want to deactivate the sent file. I just want to move it. How do I move this file using muttrc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the full filename using `record`:

```
set record = "~/.mutt/sent"
```

You could also use `+` to place your sent mail in a mailbox alongside your other mailboxes (thanks to [grochmal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/172635/grochmal) for the suggestion):

```
set record = "+sent"
```

The mailbox location is set using the `folder` variable, and is `~/Mail` by default.

Comment: I was missing the full filename. Thanks a bunch. This solved my issue.